# Unity object rotates despite Freeze

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, game-physics

I am making a game in Unity, but there is a problem with an object rotation: I have a coordinate frozen, but it still rotates after I move the object:

https://youtu.be/tVwGnWVi_Eo

On the video I move the object and when I release all the keys it rotates despite the Freeze option.

Here is my Movement script:

```
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
     public int speed;
     public int turningForce;
     private int jumpForce;
     public int jumpForceMax;

     public Rigidbody rb;

     bool doJump;

     void Start()
     {

     }

     private void Update()
     {
         if (Input.GetKeyUp("space"))
         {
             doJump = true;
         }
     }

     void FixedUpdate()
     {
         if (Input.GetKey("space") && IsOnGround)
         {
             if (jumpForce < jumpForceMax)
             {
                 jumpForce += 50;
             }
         }

         if (Input.GetKey("w") && IsOnGround)
         {
             rb.AddRelativeForce(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
         }

         if (Input.GetKey("a"))
         {
             rb.AddTorque(new Vector3(0, -speed * Time.deltaTime, 0));
         }

         if (Input.GetKey("d"))
         {
             rb.AddTorque(new Vector3(0, speed * Time.deltaTime, 0));
         }

         if (doJump)
         {
             rb.AddForce(0, jumpForce, 0);
             doJump = false;
             jumpForce = 0;
         }
     }

     private bool m_IsOnGround;

     public bool IsOnGround
     {
         get
         {
             if (m_IsOnGround)
             {
                 m_IsOnGround = false;
                 return true;
             }
             else
             {
                 return false;
             }
         }
     }

     void OnCollisionStay()
     {
         m_IsOnGround = true;
     }
 }
```

As you can see, there is no transform.position changes and the Freeze Y option is enabled.

Hopefully someone can help me to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where exactly you've frozen the Y Rotation but

`rb.AddTorque(new Vector3(0, -speed * Time.deltaTime, 0));`

Is a function that rotates a Rigidbody using force
What is the point of this if you have frozen the rotation?

[image]

If you have frozen the rotation of the component like this, the function
`AddTorque()` will not work.

Comment: This is actually strange, you are right, although despite the rotation is frozen the function AddTorque() works... Please check the video, you should be able to see Freeze option enabled.

Comment: I think it is also worth mentioning that I can see that the Freeze option actually works (not including this random rotation after the movement). If I disable the Freeze, the object will immediately rotate down the slope.

Comment: If you do not want it to rotate, just disable that function in your code. Make it a comment and it will stop rotating when you hold/press "A" or "D". Your code simply does what it's asked to.

Comment: Please check this video:
https://youtu.be/iugRjSWY0qg
I have disabled my Movement script, but as you can see the object still rotates despite it is frozen. My question is: why does it rotate?

Comment: Freezing just one axis wont stop the rigidbody from rotating.

Comment: But it rotates on the frozen axis.